# phpunit avoid constructor arguments for mock

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

What is the way to avoid phpunit having to call the constructor for a mock object? Otherwise I would need a mock object as constructor argument, another one for that etc. The api seems to be like this:

```
getMock($className, $methods = array(), array $arguments = array(),
        $mockClassName = '', $callOriginalConstructor = TRUE,
        $callOriginalClone = TRUE, $callAutoload = TRUE)
```

I don't get it to work. It still complains about the constructor argument, even with `$callOriginalConstructor` set to false.

I only have one object in the constructor and it is a dependency injection. So I don't think I have a design problem there.

Answer (score 156):

You can use `getMockBuilder` instead of just `getMock`:

```
$mock = $this->getMockBuilder('class_name')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMock();
```

See the section on ["Test Doubles"](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html) in [PHPUnit's documentation](http://phpunit.de/manual) for details.

Although you can do this, it's much better to not need to. You can refactor your code so instead of a concrete class (with a constructor) needing to be injected, you only depend upon an interface. This means you can mock or stub the interface without having to tell PHPUnit to modify the constructor behaviour.

Comment: This works great for me.  It should be example 10.3, though.  I tried to edit the post but SO kicked it back for being too short an edit.

Answer (score 43):

Here you go:

```
    // Get a Mock Soap Client object to work with.
    $classToMock = 'SoapClient';
    $methodsToMock = array('__getFunctions');
    $mockConstructorParams = array('fake wsdl url', array());
    $mockClassName = 'MyMockSoapClient';
    $callMockConstructor = false;
    $mockSoapClient = $this->getMock($classToMock,
                                     $methodsToMock,
                                     $mockConstructorParams,
                                     $mockClassName,
                                     $callMockConstructor);
```

Comment: This seems to be almost what I want. I want to call the getMock with only class to be mocked and the $callMockConstructor. How? something like this: $this->getMock($classToMock, $callMockConstructor). The only thing I could think of is to go in the source of PHPUnit and change it to default = false.

Comment: I changed the default to false in testcase.php. You would think it would be set for false by default. Mocking a constructor seems very odd

Comment: Excellent answer.  Just what I was looking for

Answer (score 8):

This question is a little old, but for new visitors, you can do it using the `createMock` method (previously called `createTestDouble` and introduced in v5.4.0).

```php
$mock = $this->createMock($className);
```

As you can see in the code below extracted from the `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` class (in `phpunit/src/framework/TestCase.php`), **it will basically create a mock object without calling the original constructor**.

```php
/** PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase::createMock method */
protected function createMock(string $originalClassName): MockObject
{
    return $this->getMockBuilder($originalClassName)
                ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                ->disableOriginalClone()
                ->disableArgumentCloning()
                ->disallowMockingUnknownTypes()
                ->getMock();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As an addendum, I wanted to attach `expects()` calls to my mocked object and then call the constructor.  In PHPUnit 3.7.14, the object that is returned when you call `disableOriginalConstructor()` is literally an object.

```
// Use a trick to create a new object of a class
// without invoking its constructor.
$object = unserialize(
sprintf('O:%d:"%s":0:{}', strlen($className), $className)
```

Unfortunately, in PHP 5.4 there is a new option which they aren't using:

[ReflectionClass::newInstanceWithoutConstructor](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstancewithoutconstructor.php)

Since this wasn't available, I had to manually reflect the class and then invoke the constructor.

```
$mock = $this->getMockBuilder('class_name')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMock();

$mock->expect($this->once())
    ->method('functionCallFromConstructor')
    ->with($this->equalTo('someValue'));

$reflectedClass = new ReflectionClass('class_name');
$constructor = $reflectedClass->getConstructor();
$constructor->invoke($mock);
```

Note, if `functionCallFromConstruct` is `protected`, you specifically have to use `setMethods()` so that the protected method is mocked.  Example:

```
    $mock->setMethods(array('functionCallFromConstructor'));
```

`setMethods()` must be called before the `expect()` call.  Personally, I chain this after `disableOriginalConstructor()` but before `getMock()`.

Comment: No idea if this is a code smell, but this worked great for me and I just wanted to thank you.

Comment: 4 hours. 4 long hours. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could add a parameter to [getMock](https://damienflament.github.io/phpunit-mock-objects-api-docs/4.0.0/PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Generator.html#method_getMock) to prevent the calling of the default constructor.

```
$mock = $this->getMock(class_name, methods = array(), args = array(), 
        mockClassName = '', callOriginalConstructor = FALSE);
```

Still, I think the answer of dave1010 looks nicer, this is just for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to create a stub to pass in as the constructor argument. Then you can break that chain of mock objects.

Answer (score 0):

PHPUnit is designed to call the constructor on mocked objects; to prevent this you should either:

1. Inject a mock object as a dependency into the object you're having trouble mocking
2. Create a test class that extends the class you're trying to call that doesn't call the parent constructor