# PHPUnit, mock constructor?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I want to mock the constructor like any other methods. I also added a willReturnCallback clause, which does not seem to work. I mean, it all works with methods, but not with the constructor.

```
$mock = $this->getMock ('MyClass', array(), array(), '', false);
$mock->expects($this->once())->method('__construct')->willReturnCallback(function() { echo 'outputt'; });
```

so mocking constructor has no effect.

Comment: yes, "refactor the code" - its a legacy code....

Comment: possible duplicate of [phpunit avoid constructor arguments for mock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279493/phpunit-avoid-constructor-arguments-for-mock)

Comment: The original constructor is called during mock construction (it just calls the baseclass' constructor). If you don't want that, you can also disable it. However, I wonder why you want to mock the constructor? The point is that unless you explicitly call it (which would be a code smell), creating the mock does the construction, so it's too late to expect a constructor call!

Comment: Besides all limitations of mocking, a controller can *never* return anything, so the mock doesn't mean anything at the moment.

Comment: You mean constructor, not controller, @WouterJ.

Comment: yea, in kind you are all true.
The problem is, the constructor does more than initialization, it actually "echo"-es something. Nevertheless, I refractored that "legacy" code, I guess that was the only solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the relevant comments as community wiki answer because there will never be another answer than "not logically possibly":

> The original constructor is called during mock construction (it just calls the baseclass' constructor). If you don't want that, you can also disable it. However, I wonder why you want to mock the constructor? The point is that unless you explicitly call it (which would be a code smell), creating the mock does the construction, so it's too late to expect a constructor call
>
> Besides all limitations of mocking, a <del>controller</del>constructor can never return anything, so the mock doesn't mean anything at the moment